# Python not raising an exception on % without conversion specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

The % operator for string formatting is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Usually, when presented a string without conversion specifier, it will raise a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. For instance, `"" % 1` will fail. So far, so good.

Sometimes, it won't fail, though, if the argument on the right of the % operator is something empty: `"" % []`, or `"" % {}` or `"" % ()` will silently return the empty string, and it looks fair enough.

The same with `"%s"` instead of the empty string will convert the empty object into a string, except the last which will fail, but I think it's an instance of the problems of the % operator, which are solved by the `format` method.

There is also the case of a non-empty dictionary, like `"" % {"a": 1}`, which works because it's really supposed to be used with named type specifiers, like in `"%(a)d" % {"a": 1}`.

However, there is one case I don't understand: `"" % b"x"` will return the empty string, no exception raised. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that:
` "" % b"x"`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>`
`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting*`

What's your python version?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's Python 3.4.2, 32 bits, on Windows. Your comment makes me think it may be a bug after all. (yes, thanks for the tag)

Comment: Added python-3.x tag. I've tried with python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but after a quick look in the [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c), I guess the reason is the following:

when there's only one argument on the right of `%`, Python looks if it has the `getitem` method, and, if yes, assumes it to be a mapping and expects us to use named formats like `%(name)s`. Otherwise, Python creates a single-element tuple from the argument and performs positional formatting. Argument count is not checked with mappings, therefore, since `bytes` and `lists` do have `getitem`, they won't fail:

```
>>> "xxx" % b'a'
'xxx'
>>> "xxx" % ['a']
'xxx'
```

Consider also:

```
>>> class X: pass
... 
>>> "xxx" % X()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

>>> class X:
...    def __getitem__(self,x): pass
... 
>>> "xxx" % X()
'xxx'
```

Strings are exception of this rule - they have `getitem`, but are still "tuplified" for positional formatting:

```
>>> "xxx" % 'a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Of course, this "sequences as mappings" logic doesn't make much sense, because formatting keys are always strings:

```
>>> "xxx %(0)s" % ['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

but I doubt anyone is going to fix that, given that `%` is abandoned anyways.

Comment: With support for `%` formating for `bytes` objects (which do fix this case), I suspect this can still be considered a bug though.

Comment: The idea looks nice, however `"%d" % b"a"` raises an exception (one could expect that it would return `"97"`, using getitem to return an integer)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: no, getitem is only invoked for named placeholders like `%(name)s`. Unnamed placeholders are always positional.

Comment: Yes, I saw it after my comment. Actually, it would make sense if "%(0)d" was accepted, but it's not. I didn't pay enough attention to the end of your post at first :-)

Answer (score 2):

The offending line is at [unicodeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b343b1734733aa578efcd855452ee1fd2defdb74/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14708). It considers all objects that are "mappings", and explicitly are not either tuples or strings, or subclasses thereof, as "dictionaries", and for those it is not error if not all arguments are converted.

The [`PyMapping_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b343b1734733aa578efcd855452ee1fd2defdb74/Objects/abstract.c#L1920) is defined as:

```
int
PyMapping_Check(PyObject *o)
{
    return o && o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping &&
        o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_subscript;
}
```

That is, any type with `tp_as_mapping` defined and that having `mp_subscript` is a mapping.

And `bytes` does [define that](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b343b1734733aa578efcd855452ee1fd2defdb74/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1633), as does any other object with `__getitem__`. Thus in Python 3.4 at least, no object with `__getitem__` will fail as the rightside argument to the `%` format op.

Now this is a change from Python 2.7. Furthermore, the reason for this is that it is that there is no way to detect all possible types that could be used for `%(name)s` formatting, except by accepting *all* types that implement `__getitem__`, though the most obvious mistakes have been taken out. When the Python 3 was published, no one added `bytes` there, though it clearly shouldn't support strings as arguments to `__getitem__`; but neither is there `list` there.

Another oversight is that a list cannot be used for formatting for positional parameters.